# LightGBM unexpected behaviour outside of jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, lightgbm

I have this strange but when I'm using a LightGBM model to calculate some predictions.

I **trained a LightGBM model inside of jupyter** and dumped it into a file using pickle. This **model** is **used in an external class**.

My problem is when I call my **prediction** function from this external class **outside of jupyter it always predicts an output of 0.5** (on all rows). When I use the exact same class **inside of jupyter I get the expected output**. In both cases the exact same model is used with the exact same data.

How can this behavior be explained and how can I achieve to get the same results outside of jupyter? Has it something to do with the fact I trained the model inside of jupyter? (I can't imagine why it would, but atm have no clue where this bug is coming from)

Edit: Used versions:
Both times the same lgb version is used (2.2.3), I also checked the python version which are equal (3.6.8) and all system paths (sys.path output). The paths are equal except of  '/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions' and '/home/xxx/.ipython'.

Edit 2: I copied the code I used inside of my jupyter and ran it as a normal python file. The model made this way works now inside of jupyter and outside of it. I still wonder why this bug accrued.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be a jupyter problem since jupyter is just an interface to communicate with python. The problem could be that you are using different python environment and different version of lgbm... Check `import lightgbm as lgb` and `lgb.__version__` on both jupyter and your python terminal and make sure there are the same (or check if there has been some major changements between these versions)

Comment: thanks for your response. Both times the same lgb version is used (2.2.3), I also checked the python version which are equal (3.6.8) and all system paths (sys.path output). The paths are equal except of  '/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions' and '/home/xxx/.ipython'.